# How to add and remove "custom" tabs in C#

Tags: c#, tabs, tabcontrol

I am making an application that requires tabs (tab-control) to be added or removed. I have done the add and remove for tabs fine, but I have custom buttons instead of using the tabs. (This button will go the the first tab page when clicked):

```
    //This will make it go to TAB 1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0; 
    }

   //This will change the MOUSEENTER to the correct image
    private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(button1_MouseEnter);
        this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Tab_Down));
    }
    //This will change the MOUSELEAVE to the correct image
    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(button1_MouseLeave);
        this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Tab_Norm));
    }
```

However, how will I create it so when you click the "Add Tab" button it creates a new tab but it also creates a new button with `tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;` in it for example.

**Edit**

I have done this to add a new tab (to tabControl1):

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
    }
```

This adds a new tab  on top of the existing ones fine. But I how do I do it so that it also creates a new button with the properties of the button above but makes it so instead of `tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;` it does `tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 3;` and goes up every time I add a new tab? - Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few updates here is a new version of my answer. It shows you how to

- Add a `Button` which adds a new `TabPages` and selects it
- Make the `Tab` control draw closing 'x' characters to the right of each tab, like Firefox or Visual Studio do it.

Make the add `Button` like you want it, maybe the Text="+" and the height like the  tabs' height. It is automatically positioned on the tab. You may need to reposition it, if your `Tab` is moved or resized.

In the `Form_Load` event the `Tab` is set to `OwnerDrawFixed` and each page's text is append by a few blanks to make room for the closing x. The code creates a class variable `closeX` to hold the current x-rectangle and tests it in the `MouseClick` event.

Make sure to wire up the `tabControl1_DrawItem` and `tabControl1_MouseClick` events!

```
    private void cb_addPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString() + "   ";
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = myTabPage;
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        cb_addPage.Top = tabControl1.Top;
        cb_addPage.Left = tabControl1.Right - cb_addPage.Width;
        foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages) tp.Text += "   ";
    }


    Rectangle closeX = Rectangle.Empty;

    private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Size xSize = new Size(13,13);
        TabPage tp = tabControl3.TabPages[e.Index];
        e.DrawBackground();
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)  )
               e.Graphics.DrawString(tp.Text+ "   ", e.Font,  brush, 
                                     e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 4 );

        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
           closeX = new Rectangle(
               e.Bounds.Right - xSize.Width, e.Bounds.Top, xSize.Width, xSize.Height);
           using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray))
                e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, brush, 
                                       e.Bounds.Right - xSize.Width, e.Bounds.Y + 4);
        }

    }

    private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (closeX.Contains(e.Location))
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
    }
```

If you want to use an Image to adorn the tabs, include an ImageList with your form, load it with the Image(s) and if the close button is the 1st image, change the code like this:

```
    if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
    {
        closeX = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Right - xSize.Width - 3, 
                               e.Bounds.Top + 5, xSize.Width, xSize.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[0], closeX, 
                             new Rectangle(0,0,16,16), GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
    }
```

I append a screenshot of the Tab with a few pages

[image: owner drawn tab with closing button]

And one using this  [image]  close button image:

[image]

**Update:** Note that if your `TabPage` contains `IDisposable` objects you should make sure they all get disposed before you remove the page! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084104/add-a-right-click-event-to-a-tab-in-a-tabcontrol-container/33084623#33084623) for example code!

Comment: Ah right, I'm glad that I am able to do it. Thanks very much, I know I have asked a lot but I guess I can just change the picture of the button and the X next to it? - Thanks

Comment: In the code as it is both are text. Yes, you could change it, but it'll take a bit of understanding the details of Graphics.DrawImage (instead of the DrawString) to change the 'x' to an image.. But: Have a look at the VS and FF! They look just like it. There was a time when images with red Xs were used but today things are more subdued.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It is now working fine, but if you are up to it how can I create a new tab with content on it for example every tab that is created has a button on it in the same place and it is the same button. Is there a way to copy it? Thanks

Comment: Copy? no. You add controls either by a routine that does just that or by one that clones a template page. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315485/adding-a-twin-tabpage-to-tabcontrol-through-a-user-command/26315755?noredirect=1#comment41299093_26315755) for an example that adds a label and a textbox to each new page.. It also adds an event with code to one of the controls (the textbox).

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. I will work on getting that done. I know that you said `Graphics.DrawImage` is a bit advanced but I have looked at some stuff, I have managed to implement it however it takes away the tabs and does not show images?

Comment: _it takes away the tabs and does not show images?_ no, it shouldn't do any of that. can you post the image you want to display?

Comment: Sorry, my explaining was bad there. I meant "I have managed to put it so an image can be displayed. But when I run it, the image does not show up" This is when I was trying to get the `Graphics.DrawImage` to work.

Comment: Ahh nice, it looks good like that. Another question (sorry if I keep asking), is there a way to change how the actual tab looks so I can use an image for the actual tab as well as the X button?

Comment: If you look at the code, you'll see that all you see in the tab in actually drawn in my code. So, yes you can draw the whole tabs, too. You may need to make the font larger to make the tabs grow, too as this is the only way to control their height..

Comment: Ahh right, I have done some playing around with it but I cannot get it to work (to draw the tabs as images). Is it correct that I am changing the `e.DrawBackground;` to `e.Graphics.DrawImage`? Or is that not correct? - Thanks

Comment: well, I would keep the background, but then add the drawimage. you may want to put up a new question, with your code and also the image(s) you are trying to use. Aslo don't forget to clearly describe what goes wrong!

Comment: Ahh ok, I will create a new question on it. Thanks for all the help!