# How to set the color of a close button for a tab page in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a tab control say tabMain . In the first tab which is my Home tab I have a dropdown and an Add Button. When I click the add button a new tab would be opened with the selected item as tab header. Along with the tab header I need to include a close button . Right now I have the close button But I also need to set a background color for the close button. Here is a portion of my code.

```
 TabPage newTabPage= new TabPage();   
 newTabPage.Text = cmbType.SelectedItem.ToString() +"  X";
 tabMain.TabPages.Add(newTabPage);
```

In my mouse down event I have included the function for close.

```
 private void tabMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            if (tabMain.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                Rectangle r = tabMain.GetTabRect(tabMain.SelectedIndex);                    
                Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 15, r.Y, 15, 18);

                if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Would you like to Close this Tab?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        this.tabMain.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabMain.SelectedIndex);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception in closing a tab");
        }
    }
```

My close button is working fine. But I need to set a color for the close button . I have also tried including a label . Here is the code

```
TabPage newTabPage = new TabPage();                
Label labelClose = new Label();
labelClose.Text = "  X";
labelClose.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;               
newTabPage.Text = cmbType.SelectedItem.ToString() + labelClose.Text;
tabMain.TabPages.Add(newTabPage);
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have a close button, you have a rectangle with the name closeButton that kinda mimics a button. If you want a closebutton and want to colorize it, use a real button, and attach an eventhandler to the click event.This code would be a lot simpler than what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck : Yea..u r right.. I can add a button Close also.. But again though I add a button how to set the color only for that?

Comment: through its properties of course , your problem becomes really simple once you use a normal button. Take a look at your own code where you set the backcolor of your label.

Comment: You should custom draw your tab control. this [link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29206-Custom-drawn-Close-button-TabControl.aspx) may help you. Also check this [link](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/11/make-an-owner-drawn-tabcontrol-in-c/)

Comment: Or move to WPF where adding a button in the tab header is a lot easier. Question is do you really want a button in that header.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck : I have tried with button and setting its property before trying label. It dint work.

Comment: Because you are in the tabheader, you cannot use a button control (my mistake I missed that), you have to use an owner drawn tab control, which is a bit harder, or make a WPF application where adding buttons in the tab header is possible without any code.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck  Wish I could..I have seen many sites where the close button is implemented in wpf .. but alas. my entire team is working on win forms. So can't switch to wpf at this moment :(

Comment: This really should be done by owner drawing the Tab! [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315025/how-to-add-and-remove-custom-tabs-in-c-sharp/26315325?s=2|0.1553#26315325)

Answer (score 0):

To add a background color to the rectangle you need to do the following:

> To draw a Rectangle filled with color, you need a Graphics object and
>   an object derived from Brush such as SolidBrush or
>   LinearGradientBrush. The Graphics object provides the FillRectangle
>   method and the Brush object provides the color and fill information.

```
//Create graphic object for the current form
Graphics gs = this.CreateGraphics();
//Create a rectangle object
Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 15, r.Y, 15, 18);
//Fill the rectangle with red color
gs.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), closeButton);
```

Comment: thanks . But it dint help.. I have tried this also already..but it doesnt work. :(

Comment: Graphics is a disposable object, use the using mechanism or dispose the graphics object when you are done.