# Add a right click event to a tab in a TabControl container

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol

In a form I have a tab container in which I dynamically add tabs through the use of a button. As there is no easy way that I know of (then again I'm a WinForms newbie) to close the selected tab, I'd like to set up an event handler for handling a right click through which the tab will close. In simple words I want to right-click on the selected tab in order to close it.

This is the event handler which I have written (yet doesn't work):

```
private void tab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
        if (sender == tabControl1.SelectedTab && me.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
        }
    }
```

I guess it's too naive of an approach? The handler does not even register the right click when I click on the tab. Any suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: Is closing a tab the same as removing if from the tab control, or is closing a tab the same as showing another tab?

Comment: Removing it from the tab control.

Comment: look in to `MouseUp / MouseDown` events instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it doesn't work means: tab_click is not called? sender is not the selectedtab? me.Button is not as expected or is the tab not removed?

Comment: It means that the handler (tab_click) is not called. I checked with the debugger.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (for you to not use an event as `TabPage_Click` which is accessed a lot; and for the user) to add a closing button to each tab and include the tab-closing actions in the `Click` event of that button? Something like: `private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(N);
}` where N is the tab number. You can take this number in the button name or even as an independent variable in its Tag property. All the buttons might use the same method. As far as you are adding the tabs are runtime, why not adding some lines more for the buttons?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315025/how-to-add-and-remove-custom-tabs-in-c-sharp/26315325?s=2|0.3657#26315325) for an example of how to add a __Close__ and also an __Add__ button to a Tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void tabControl1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got very iffy code here.  Don't blindly cast an EventArgs object, simply use the MouseClick event instead.  Don't blindly hope that the SelectedTab is the one that was clicked, that happen later.  And never, *never* use the Remove() method like that, it is super-duper important to dispose the TabPage and its controls.  If you don't then those controls will permanently leak, the kind of bug that eventually crashes your program with an undebuggable exception like "Error creating window".

Make it look like this instead:

```
private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < tabControl1.TabCount; ++ix) {
            if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(ix).Contains(e.Location)) {
                tabControl1.TabPages[ix].Dispose();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to navigate directly to the tab that triggered the event instead of traversing the whole container?

Comment: @AutomEng, not as far as I could see. The tab pages are simple containers, they have no information on their headers. Those are handled and rendered by the tab control itself, which is why this loop is needed.